# Passing parameter to Controller by using ajax

Tags: java, html, mysql, ajax, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Used Spring boot, MySQL, JPA and RESTFUL CRUD API.

What I'm trying to do is passing the parameter to Controller so that the parameter goes into the table. But null values go into the table and I can't figure out which part is the problem. Only I can sure about is that the Controller doesn't receive the appropriate value.

Under below, I posted Entity class(Status.java), Controller(GuideController.java) and html form(guide.html).

Status.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_status")
public class Status {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

private Integer id;

private String xml_to_json;


public String getXml_to_json() {
    return xml_to_json;
}

public void setXml_to_json(String xml_to_json) {
    this.xml_to_json = xml_to_json;
}
```

GuideController.java

```
    @Autowired
private StatusRepository statusRepository;

@GetMapping(path="/insert") // Map ONLY GET Requests
public @ResponseBody String addNewStatus (@RequestParam String xml_to_json
        , @RequestParam String json_to_xml) {
    // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
    // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

    Status s = new Status();
    s.setXml_to_json(xml_to_json);
    //s.setJson_to_xml(json_to_xml);
    statusRepository.save(s);
    return "Saved";
}

@GetMapping(path="/all")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<Status> getAllUsers() {
    // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
    return statusRepository.findAll();
}
```

guide.html

```
var xml2json = function(_data){
$.ajax({   
    type: "POST",   
    url: url + "xml2json",   
    data: _data,
    contentType : "application/xml",
    cache: false,
    success : function(data) {   
        $("#output-xml-to-json").html(JSON.stringify(data,null,4));
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: url + "insert",
            data: {xml_to_json:"success"},
            contentType: "text"
        })
    },
    error : function(){
        $("#output-xml-to-json").html("xml2json error");
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: url + "insert",
            data: {xml_to_json:"error"},
            contentType: "text"
        })
    }
});
```

}

Comment: you are passing 'xml_to_json' this parameter to controller, print this in controller to verify its value as 'success' or null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request mapping is GET:

```
@GetMapping(path="/insert") // Map ONLY GET Requests
public @ResponseBody String addNewStatus (@RequestParam String xml_to_json
    , @RequestParam String json_to_xml) {...}
```

And the AJAX request is POST with json data. The AJAX request should be get and `xml_to_json` has to be passed in query string.